# Mustache - send array to js function

Tags: templates, mustache

I have following problem

DATA:

```
var json = {'data': [{'id': '1', 'members': [{'name':'First member', 'age': '23'},{'name':'Second member', 'age': '31'}] }]}
```

JSON is written from the top of my head so it may be invalid, not so important.

MUSTACHE.tmpl

```
{{#data}}
{{#members}}
<script>myJsFunction( all_members_attributes_as_json )</script>
{{/members}}
{{/data}}
```

So in general, I'd like to pass whole mustache array to my JS function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About like this:

Add a function for mapping your members to JSON strings:

```
_.each(json.data, function(el) {
    el.jsonMembers = function() {
        return _.map(this.members, function(member) {
            return JSON.stringify(member);
        });
    };
});
```

Note that I used `_.each` and `_.map` here... If you don't use Underscore, replace with your favorite iterators, or a vanilla for loop. Or just use Underscore, because it makes life better.

Then you'd access the stringified versions instead of the normal ones:

```
{{#data}}
{{#jsonMembers}}
<script>myJsFunction({{{ . }}})</script>
{{/jsonMembers}}
{{/data}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. And you were right.. Underscore made my life easier. I'm amused :)